# If $2$ divides a number $a$, does $2^n$ divide $a$ ? $n$ is any integar

Tags: number-theory, divisibility

If $2$ divides a number $a$, does $2^n$ divide $a$ ? $n$ is any integer.

This seems to be true for me, but I just want to make sure it applies for all numbers.

example

if a = 137

2 does not divide 137
4 does not divide 137
8 does not divide 137 and so on

Comment: What multiple of what divides what? The way I read this you claim that if $2 \mid a$, then $2n \mid a$ for every integer $n$. That's clearly wrong.

Comment: What happens if $a=2$? Or are you wanting to ask about $2$ dividing multiples of $a$?

Comment: hi thank you for the respond I have changed the question please read it now.

Comment: No. 2 divides 6, but $8=2^3$ does not divide 6.

Comment: $2$ divides $2$ but $2^2$ does not :)

Answer (score 1):

$2$ divides $4$

$2\cdot 4=8$ does not divide $4$

Over and Done!!

Answer (score 0):

Edit: question was changed again, my answer is no longer valid.

**Yes**, if a divides b then a divides the multiples of b.

Consider b/a = c, where c is a whole number. Take any number d, and multiply it by b. This gives us bd. By our formula early, this means bd/a = dc, where dc is the product of two whole numbers 9i.e, another whole number). This is true for any a, b and d where a divides b.

Answer (score 0):

Do you now mean

> does $2^n$ divide $a^n$?

Let $a=2b$, then $a^n=(2b)^n=2^nb^n$

Comment: what I mean is basically this
 let a= 137

2 does not divide 137
2 x 2 = 4 does not divide 137
2x2x2 = 8 does not divide 137 

seems like 2^n doesn't divide 137

Comment: @user142405 That is a completely different question. You have observed that if $a$ is odd (another way of saying that $2$ does not divide $a$) and $n\ge 1$ then $2^n$ does not divide $a$ - suppose it did so that $a=2^nb$ then $a=2\cdot 2^{n-1}b$.